# Angular-UI-Grid integration with angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am getting below error while using Angular-UI-Grid in angular 1.5 application.

> > ajax.ts:153 GET http://localhost:5000/ui-grid/uiGridRenderContainer 404 (Not Found) XMLHttpRequest.send @ ajax.ts:153 (anonymous) @
> >     angular.js:11756 m @ angular.js:11517 c @ angular.js:11227 a @
> >     angular.js:15961 (anonymous) @ angular.js:15977 $eval @
> >     angular.js:17229 $digest @ angular.js:17045 $digest @ inspector.js:126
> >     $apply @ angular.js:17337 l @ angular.js:11572 C @ angular.js:11778
> >     x.onload @ angular.js:11711 load (async) (anonymous) @
> >     angular.js:11694 m @ angular.js:11517 c @ angular.js:11227 a @
> >     angular.js:15961 (anonymous) @ angular.js:15977 $eval @
> >     angular.js:17229 $digest @ angular.js:17045 $digest @ inspector.js:126
> >     $apply @ angular.js:17337 l @ angular.js:11572 C @ angular.js:11778
> >     x.onload @ angular.js:11711 load (async) (anonymous) @
> >     angular.js:11694 m @ angular.js:11517 c @ angular.js:11227 a @
> >     angular.js:15961 (anonymous) @ angular.js:15977 $eval @
> >     angular.js:17229 $digest @ angular.js:17045 $digest @ inspector.js:126
> >     $apply @ angular.js:17337 l @ angular.js:11572 C @ angular.js:11778
> >     x.onload @ angular.js:11711 load (async) (anonymous) @
> >     angular.js:11694 m @ angular.js:11517 c @ angular.js:11227 a @
> >     angular.js:15961 (anonymous) @ angular.js:15977 $eval @
> >     angular.js:17229 $digest @ angular.js:17045 $apply @ angular.js:17337
> >     l @ angular.js:11572 C @ angular.js:11778 x.onload @ angular.js:11711
> >     load (async) (anonymous) @ angular.js:11694 m @ angular.js:11517 c @
> >     angular.js:11227 a @ angular.js:15961 (anonymous) @ angular.js:15977
> >     $eval @ angular.js:17229 $digest @ angular.js:17045 $apply @
> >     angular.js:17337 (anonymous) @ angular.js:1749 a @ angular.js:4665 a @
> >     angular.js:1747 oe @ angular.js:1767 ie @ angular.js:1652 (anonymous)
> >     @ angular.js:30863 n @ angular.js:3166 Ye @ angular.js:3456 n @
> >     angular.js:3444 LogCopyService.ts:64 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed
> >     to load template: ui-grid/uiGridRenderContainer (HTTP status: 404 Not
> >     Found)

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you follow [this tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20101%20Intro%20to%20UI-Grid)? Hard to tell, since there's no code included in your question...

Comment: Thanks @Remko for your answer...Yes i am following the given link. But My problem is when i am calling the UI-grid directive its hitting GET http://localhost:5000/ui-grid/uiGridRenderContainer 404 (Not Found) url and giveing the above mentioned console error.